# Problems with generating WCF wsdl client with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, .net-core, wsdl

I try to connect to a open API: https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/wsdl/sweaWS_ssl.wsdl

I generate the client just fine in VS 2019 16.7.1 and the Reference.cs file is created

When I try to execute the remote function I get a 404.

With postman I can execute the remote function just fine, but I notice that I need to use this exact Content-type and request otherwise I also get a 404

Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="urn:getCalendarDays"

Request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://swea.riksbank.se/xsd">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <xsd:getCalendarDays>
            <datefrom>2019-08-12</datefrom>
            <dateto>2021-08-12</dateto>
        </xsd:getCalendarDays>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

With above postman settings I get a response with correct data.

But if I try todo the same through my client I get a 404. So I though I would debug the WCF client with fiddler, but I cant seem to add a proxy to it, my code

```
        var client = new SweaWebServicePortTypeClient(SweaWebServicePortTypeClient.EndpointConfiguration.SweaWebServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint, new EndpointAddress("https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/services/SweaWebServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint"));
        var binding = client.Endpoint.Binding as CustomBinding;
        var htbe = binding.Elements.Find<HttpTransportBindingElement>();

        var prox = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();

        htbe.ProxyAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8866");
        htbe.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        htbe.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
        //htbe.ProxyAuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;

        var days = await client.getCalendarDaysAsync(DateTime.UtcNow.Date, DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(31));
```

call to client.getCalendarDaysAsync generates this exception

> 'When using a non-null Proxy, the WindowsProxyUsePolicy property must be set to WindowsProxyUsePolicy.UseCustomProxy.'

Google turns up empty handed, please advice. Thanks

edit: for now I run my own client, but its messy, would like to use built in funcions if possible

```
        private async Task<Dictionary<DateTime, bool>> GetBankDaysRemote(DateTime from, DateTime to)
        {
            var format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            var message =
                $@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:xsd=""http://swea.riksbank.se/xsd"">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <xsd:getCalendarDays>
            <datefrom>{from.ToString(format)}</datefrom>
            <dateto>{to.ToString(format)}</dateto>
        </xsd:getCalendarDays>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>";

            var stream = GetTextStream(message);

            var req = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/services/SweaWebServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint"),
                Content = new StreamContent(stream)
            };
            req.Content.Headers.ContentLength = message.Length;
            req.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", @"application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=""urn:getCalendarDays""");

            var response = await client.SendAsync(req);

            await CheckResponse(response);
            var xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns0", "http://swea.riksbank.se/xsd");

            var node = xml.SelectSingleNode("//ns0:getCalendarDaysResponse", nsmgr);
            if (node == null) throw new System.Exception("Response does not contain correct getCalendarDaysResponse");
            var bankDays = (getCalendarDaysResponse)new XmlSerializer(typeof(getCalendarDaysResponse)).Deserialize(GetTextStream(node.OuterXml));
            return bankDays.@return.ToDictionary(bd => NullSafe(bd.caldate).Date, bd => bd.bankday == "Y");
        }
```

Comment: I suggest you use the .net framework to create the client, because some functions of WCF are not supported in the core, which may cause this problem.

Comment: @Dingpeng please see my updated answer, thats what I'm doing do get on with this task. But I would much rather use a proper wsdl client

Comment: The .net framework can also generate proxy classes by adding service references and does not require us to create requests ourselves.

Comment: You can refer to this link to generate proxy classes in .net: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631400/adding-wsdl-service-reference-to-vs-fail-because-generated-xsd-file-contains-ill/61725107#61725107

Comment: Using the cli generates the same code as my initially answer and with the same problems sadly

Comment: Isn't a configuration file generated when the proxy class is generated? The configuration file will contain binding configuration and endpoint information.

Answer (score 0):

The error message 'When using a non-null Proxy, the WindowsProxyUsePolicy property must be set to WindowsProxyUsePolicy.UseCustomProxy.' is related to a bug.

Solution is to update your libs to latest version.

More infos here:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23373

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1592